# How would I run code to my Raspberry PI wirelessly?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wifi, raspberry-pi3

I made a post similar to this however it was horribly worded and most of the information required to answer it was nowhere to be found - and it had reached essentially no one as a culmination of these factors.

***Alright so, the issue.***

- The IDEs on the Raspberry PI are frankly unusable. Not 'oh I don't have auto complete' unusable (though they don't) I'm talking 'the hindrance of a PI's slowness combined with questionable user interface leads to slow and unenjoyable development' unusable.

***The question itself.***

- I wish to run Python code developed on my main machine - **a windows 10 computer** - on my **Raspberry PI B+**. I've figured out SSH somewhat but it doesn't seem to really handle my problem all that well. Hopefully this is possible **without a wired connection** but if it is not I'd appreciate any links I could go to to purchase a wired component.

***Probably the serious problem.***

- I'm very new to using hardware in my programming, and fairly young as well - not even an adult -  so take my ignorance with a grain of salt.

***An edit because I can't read rules.***

- I was told in comments that Stack Overflow was not meant for asking questions without attempts. I have searched for over a week on this topic, and nothing remotely close to what I needed came up. That's why I resorted to here. Sorry I guess?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SCP to move the file to the Raspberry PI wirelessly

```
    scp [source files] [user]@[host]:[path]
```

So in this case your source file(s) would be a python file, the user would be your username on your pi, the host would be the IP of the pi, and the path would be the location you want to save to on your pi.

You should then be able to run your file through the terminal. Let me know if you have any questions.